# How to detect error values that are never used

Tags: go, goland, golangci-lint

I'm looking for a way to to find occurrences of this error "handling" that doesn't do anything with the first error:

example:

```
func handler() {
   var myErr error

   myErr = doSomething() //Warn me about this please

   myErr = doSomethingElse()

   if myErr != nil {
      return
   }

}

func doSomething() error {
    return errors.New("an example error")
}

func doSomethingElse() error {
    return errors.New("an example error")
}
```

I would like to be warned that I haven't used the error after the first call to svc.DoSomething() because its effectively overwritten and ignored.

I have tried enabling all code inspections in goland 2021.3 and have tried [staticcheck](https://staticcheck.io) and have searched for an existing linter.

I believe it should show SA4006 after the first call to svc.DoSomething() which works fine in VSCode.

Comment: Requests for resources, such as linters or tools, is off-topic here. So I've reworded your question not to ask for a tool specifically, but rather to ask how to detect such errors.

Comment: Tried [ineffassign](https://github.com/gordonklaus/ineffassign) after suggestion below in both standalone and through golangci-lint but it does not detect this case due to the `error` type in go being an `interface`.

Comment: It's certianly not related to `error` being an interface. I think you may need a different linter to detect variables that are overwritten before being read.  Not sure if that exists.

Comment: After a clean install on a new machine, `ineffassign` worked.

Comment: That's very strange!  But I'm glad it's working for you now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest the `ineffassign` linter: https://github.com/gordonklaus/ineffassign

It can be used as a standalone tool or via `golangci-lint`: https://golangci-lint.run/usage/linters/

It's not gonna check only for error, but for all useless assignments (*ie* that aren't used latter on) like in your example.

Comment: A small addition: GoLand has Go Linter plugin that shows linters errors right in the IDE: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12496-go-linter

Comment: After a clean install on a new machine, `ineffassign` worked.

Answer (score -1):

VSCode does the same thing.

[image]

After I use this variable:

[image]

Doc: `https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/internal/typesinternal#UnusedVar`

Diagnostic Tools: `https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/wiki/tools#diagnostics`

Comment: unused variables are a not valid at all. VSCode is just showing you the compiler error.